# Vertica Input Query does not support SSRS Input Parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, vertica, vsql

I am Creating SSRS reports using Vertica Data Source. I need to insert values to vertica physical table using SSRS input parameters. Build query like this:

```
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (@GUID, @EmpNo, @EmpName);
```

While executing it thorows error:

```
ERROR: Syntax error at or near ","
----------------------------
[42601] ERROR: Syntax error at or near ","
```

Meanwhile, select query works fine with SSRS input parameters, query like this:

```
select * from Employee
where GUID = @GUID`.
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See if you can find how the query was actually received by Vertica.  Maybe run it and then look at the query_requests view?

Comment: Thanks for your reply wood,  Could let me know how can i view the query_requests?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM query_requests WHERE request ilike 'select%Employee%'` or something similar